# If the hard drive is bad...?

Tags: mac, hard-drive

My Macbook has been freezing or crashing since I replaced the hard drive and restored my applications and files using Time Machine. Software diagnostics and repairs do not seem to indicate any problems on the software side (SmartUtility, Yasu). Is it possible that faulty hard disk could cause this sort of trouble, or would hardware problems lead to more catastrophic (and obvious) failures?

**Edit (details):** This replacement was just to increase my hard disk space, so no problems before. The freezing is the spinning beach ball or just pauses. The crashes are not whole OS crashes but many applications just fail to respond or access information. Rebooting seems to fix. This hadn't happened to me before the HD replacement, so this is why I suspect the HD. Thanks for your inputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm talking about my recent experience on Windows, but I think my experience over the last 2 weeks can help you. Basically my SSD drive was failing.

It took me about a week to detect the problem. The Windows Event viewer didn't exactly show any useful errors pinpointing I/O failure, but mainly this service crashed, this permission failed to be applied, this type of thing.

In the meantime regular blue screens of death, crashes reboots and freezing up.

Imo - Sure your problem can very easily be HDD related.

EDIT: As mentioned this was with an SSD drive.

Comment: Thanks -- I've ruled out most other problems so replacing HD.

Comment: Just an update -- I replaced the HD, and the problem is fixed. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

How does it crash exactly? Is it becoming unresponsive (i.e. Mouse not moving) or is it giving you the "spinning beach-ball" or is it telling you that "you have to shut-down your computer" with a grey-ish screen overlay (kernel panic)?
Also, did you replace the previous hard drive because of an error? If so, please also describe that.

Answer (score 1):

Put the old drive back in, If there are still problems then you know the issue wasn't with the new drive.

Comment: Yes, but that doesn't rule out errors in migrating applications and documents to the new drive (even if the new drive was "good").